# Как получить все ссылки на изображения js

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, chrome-extension

пишу расширения для получения всех картинок и у меня возник вопрос но я нигде не нашёл ответа.
На сайте могут быть много картинок по разным ссылка и не только в тегах img а и в скриптах и в css и могут быть разные ссылки например -

`<p> http://somylink.com/image.jpg </p>`

хоть картинка не выводиться но мне тоже надо её ссылку получить

метод сделать по `$("img")` не выйдет так как не у всех сайтах есть теги img.
например - https://www.apple.com/ru/pages/ - картинок много а тега img ни одного.

Comment: А вот такие картинки тоже url нужен? ```<img src="data:image/png;base64, AAAFCAYAA{.....}gg=="  />```

Comment: Ну если это картика - всё равно какая , то да. 
а это картинка так что нужен.

Comment: Ну тогда я вас огорчу, у вас не выйдет получить ссылку на такую картинку, данные изображения содержатся прямо в теге :)

Comment: всмысле , это как ?

Comment: Всмысле данные картинки(не ссылка а содержимое файла с картинкой) записано прямо в тег в base64 кодировке, и таких фокусов - очень много, это лишь один из примеров :) Ваша задача в ее текущем звучании сопоставима с написанием браузера с нуля и на JS, вам надо парсить HTML + CSS + JS и частично загружать данные к себе на сервер если они вшиты прямо в тело документа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам придется пройтись по всем узлам страницы и проверить содержимое, стили и атрибуты каждого из них. Примерно таким образом:

```
const body = $('body');
const check_children = function(elem){
     const child_arr = elem.children();
     if(!child_arr.length){
         return;
     }
     for(var i = 0; i < child_arr.length; i++){
         const child = $(child_arr[i]);
         find_img(child);
         check_children(child);
     }
};
```

В find_img пишете все необходимые условия. Например, маску для поиска в тексте elem.text().match(/http.+.jpg/) или проверку на наличие фона elem.css('background-image') !== 'none'